# C: Getting first 5 bits

Tags: c, binary

lets say i have this variable:

```
unsigned int a = 13428;
```

It binary values is: **11010001110100**

I want to get the first 5 bits (110100011**10100**)

I tried to do this:

```
a &= 11111; // because in left is always 0
```

What I am doing wrong? 
If I do on paper

```
11010001110100
&
00000000011111
```

It should be **00000000010100**

Comment: So, the first 5 bits are the least significant 5 bits?  `a & 0x1F` does the job.  Using `11111` uses decimal `11111`, hex `0x2867`, binary `0b0010'0100'0110'0111` (C++14 notation) as the mask, giving the wrong result.

Comment: `11111` is decimal. You want `0x1F` (or `31`. or `037`)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler so the first bits start from left of right? In school I learned from right.

Comment: @EugeneSh. or `(1<<5) - 1`

Comment: @GeorgeValentin That's the reason not to call them "first" or "last", but most or least  significant ones.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what you mean — the term 'first 5 bits' is ambiguous at best, meaningless at worst, but you highlighted 5 bits (but I see you say "5 bytes" in the question, but "5 bits" in the title — did you mean "bits" or "bytes"?  If you meant bytes, then the mask must be 0xFFFFFFFFFFULL, and the type probably needs to be `unsigned long long` as `int` probably only has 4 bytes), at the least significant end of the number, so I (mis?)interpreted it as "least significant 5 bits".

Comment: It is obvious from the hilite text that OP means 5 bits, not bytes.

Comment: @EugeneSh. — Ugh; yes, and the `int` type is probably only 4 bytes anyway.

Comment: That's right, sorry, it was bits not bytes.

Comment: @WeatherVane: I agree that highlight and title both indicate 5 bits; the text does (did) say "5 bytes".  I was wondering what I misread...but I see divergent wording in the question to explain my confusion.  _[…time passed…the question is modified…]_ And the question has been fixed; bits was intended.

Comment: C sadly does not have binary expressions (although library functions may process them), but does use hexadecimal as offered in previous comments.

Comment: @WeatherVane Some compiler offer the `0b` prefix as extension. Which I would like to see as a part of the next standard revision...

Comment: So the compiler thinks that "11111" it's a decimal number and not a binary, so I have to transform that number into hexadecimal. Ok i got it, thanks you guys <3

Comment: You can also use decimal or octal as I noted in my first comment. Hex is just the most convenient one to translate from/to binary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`11111` is just eleven-thousand-hundred-and-eleven. Which is `10101101100111` in binary.

So in binary you're doing `11010001110100 & 10101101100111`, which is in binary
`10000001100100`.

Comment: It seems I can't read my terminal; I was sure `bc` told me `0x2867` but I see it actually says `0x2B67`.  Your bit pattern is correct.  The one in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47947367/c-getting-first-5-bits#comment82864584_47947367) is incorrect because of … old age and antiquity creeping up on the senescent (me).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I believe your **senescent** means just as imperfect as in earlier years, yet with greater knowledge.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I find it yelling at kids to keep off one's lawn keeps one sharp as one proceeds along the t-axis.